# How to press WebApp button using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I have an telegram userbot based on telethon and I need it to click on a button that opens a telegram webapp. How can this be implemented?

The only thing I could find is [this function](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/request_app_web_view.html), but I don't understand how to use it correctly.